# Make Leaflet map full screen without scroll bars

Tags: html, leaflet

This is probably an easy fix, but I haven't been able to figure it out. How do I get this map to show full screen without scroll bars?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tabletop@1.5.2/src/tabletop.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <script src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
    html, body{  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


 #map-div {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
      </style>    
      
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="map-div"></div>
      
<script>
var map = L.map('map-div').setView([55.676098, 12.568337], 5);
var basemap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Basemap (c) <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  //minZoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 100
});
basemap.addTo(map);


var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
    var line = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
    for (var row in data) {
    var marker = L.marker([
      data[row].Latitude,
      data[row].Longitude
    ]).addTo(fg);
    line.addLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
    marker.bindPopup('<strong>' + data[row].Info + '</strong>');
  }
  
  map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());
}


function init() {
  Tabletop.init({
    key: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rs6xPlJ8pU4UFfmokjATaf4dArMWxQxZcyS-xRIIFuY/edit?usp=sharing',
    callback: addPoints,
    simpleSheet: true
  });
}
init()
</script>     
  </body>

</html>
```

This is how the map looks now: https://enounce.github.io/

I've included all code in the HTML file, I'm not sure if it's better to call the script and css from an external source?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this CSS to your site:

```
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would just add these.... `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;` so that it goes to 100% of the screen all the time

Comment: For this purpose it makes no difference if `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;` or `height: 100%; width: 100%`  is used

Comment: The first suggestion worked wonders, as you can see from the updated map on the link. @FalkeDesign, can I ask you why just adding margin: 0; & padding: 0; inside the existing "HTML, body ..." don't produce the same results as adding the entire block by itself?

Comment: If you add `<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">` and for html the same

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answered your question...

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is very safe. `*` selects everything, including all child elements of the body.